# Find hidden padding or margin on wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have looked all through our wordpress widgets, widget settings, page settings, browser inspector, etc. and I cannot locate what's causing our site to have padding or margin on the right-hand side of the screen, but only on mobile. It also isn't happening elsewhere on the site outside of the homepage. Can anyone help me isolate what's causing it or what line of code I can add to prevent it from showing? Thanks.

https://lunarlab.io/
[Notice the dark background and then the ~20px of whitespace to the righthand side of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFS7G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with data-attribute `data-id="a3013be"` that is pushing your entire website. I supose that you can remove it from elementor in the visual composer (it should be an empty element on the page layout or something like that).

However, if you want to hide it directly with CSS you can select this data-attribute, like this: `div[data-id="a3013be"]` and set `display: none` on it.

Comment: AHH - that fixed it!! thank you so much. I have no idea what that data id but I'm glad to have it resolved. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it. The data-attributes normally are assigned to an element with a unique ID by the visual composer to identify it and execute some functions, style or whatever its need it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the animated red moon that is moving on the screen that is changing the width of your site on smaller screens. If you notice when the website is sized down to a 4:3 area, the width of the website increases and decreases when the red moon moves on and off the screen. It looks like it uses the elementor plugin. Hopefully this helps address the root of the issue.

Comment: The moons are hidden on mobile, so I don't think that's it. I suspected it might be the testimonials, but hiding that section didn't affect the padding either, so I'm at a loss.